# Injectivity of the extension of a injective function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have two questions about injectivity of holomorphic functions:

1. I know that if $f$ is a holomorphic function on a disk $U$ that is injective, then $f'(z)\not = 0$ for all $z\in U$. Does this result remain true if we take a general connected open subset, not necessarily simply connected?
2. If I have an injective function defined on the unitary disk $\mathbb{D}:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$, may have one pole inside it, and I have an holomorphic extension to a neighborhood of the closure of the disk, is the extension injective in the boundary of the unitary disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $f'(z_0)=0$ at some $z_0$ in an open set where $f$ is holomorphic, then $f$ is not injective near $z_0.$ This result is purely local.
2. Consider $e^{\pi z}.$

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it's true, because you can check the condition on a small disk-shaped neighborhood of each point individually.
2. No: the function $e^{\pi z}$ is a counterexample, as it takes the same value at $i$ and $-i$.